# Translation of van der Waerden's "Stetigkeitssätze für halbeinfache Liesche Gruppen" and Freudenthal's "Die Topologie der Lieschen Gruppen als algebraisches Phänomen".

Tags: translation, reference-request

Does anyone know of a translation into English of the 1932 paper "Stetigkeitssätze für halbeinfache Liesche Gruppen" by B. L. van der Waerden (Continuity Theorem for Semisimple Lie Groups)? Also, H. Freudenthal's 1941 "Die Topologie der Lieschen Gruppen als algebraisches Phänomen". I am gathering material for an exposition on Lie theory, and am so utterly smitten by van der Waerden's dazzling little paper that I have a good mind to translate it myself and include it as an appendix. Of course firstly, if it's already done, this would save me work and secondly, German is not my mother tongue, so, whilst the paper's wonderful clarity and simple, strong ideas makes me highly confident I can translate the ideas and mathematics accurately, I am not sure all German speakers would like my translation down to the wordly level. I may also include extracts of the Freudenthal paper.

Comment: It's unlikely that translations exist, unfortunately.  By the way, Freudenthal's 1941 *Ann. of Math.* paper had roman numeral I in the title, but apparently no part II appeared.  Some corrections were published in 1946.  Freudenthal himself reviewed (in English) an announcement by Tits of the substantial Borel-Tits project generalizing that 1941 paper in the setting of algebraic groups: MR0379749 (52 #654) J.Tits, Homomorphismes “abstraits” de groupes de Lie.  Symposia Mathematica XIII, pp. 479–499. Academic Press, London, 1974.